# Why does this simple server fail on very low concurrent request?

Tags: c++, sockets, pthreads

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

int f(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return 1;
    return x % 100;
}

void *deal(void *arg) {
    int fd = * (int *) arg;
    int x;
    int n = read(fd, &x, sizeof x);
    if (n < 0) std::cout << "error reading"  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "request " << x << " received" << std::endl;
    int y = f(x);
    write(fd, &y, sizeof y);
    std::cout << "response to " << x << ": " << y << std::endl;
    close(fd);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    bind(socket_fd, (sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof addr);
    listen(socket_fd, 20);
    std::cout << "listen on " << port << std::endl;
    sockaddr remote_addr;
    socklen_t len;
    for (; ;) {
        int fd = accept(socket_fd, &remote_addr, &len);
        pthread_t p;
        pthread_create(&p, NULL, deal, (void *) &fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code of the server. It simply create a new thread for each connection and then read an integer, then reply the integer % 100.

It works well when there are no concurrent requests. However, it should also work on concurrent. But it failed on just 10 concurrent requests.

Comment: It's C++. Use std::thread instead of pthreads.

Comment: The `int` pointer you pass as an argument points to an `int` that goes immediately out of scope the next time round the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the memory for `fd` time and time again in different threads. I.e. it is getting overwritten on each accept.

Change

```
pthread_create(&p, NULL, deal, (void *) &fd);
```

to

```
pthread_create(&p, NULL, deal, (void *) fd);
```

And

```
void *deal(void *arg) {
int fd = * (int *) arg;
```

to

```
void *deal(void *arg) {
int fd = (int) arg;
```